# get the closest element to a component angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a text field in an component, that when in focus, needs to populate a hidden field outside of the component that is nearest to it.

At the moment I can get the field in focus, but what I need to do now is populate the hidden field.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<input type="hidden" id="h0" name="" value="">
<app-focus></app-focus>
<input type="hidden" id="h0" name="" value="">
<app-focus></app-focus>
<input type="hidden" id="h0" name="" value="">
<app-focus></app-focus>
<input type="hidden" id="h0" name="" value="">
<app-focus></app-focus>
```

App-Focus:

```
<p>
  focus works!
  <input id="inputId" type="text" name="" value="">
</p>
```

Component:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    let dummyEl = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("#inputId")
    for(let i = 0; i < dummyEl.length; i++){
    let el = dummyEl[i]
    // if (document.activeElement === el){ stops working if I use this
       console.log(document.activeElement === el)
        console.log(el.closest("#h0"))//always returns null

// }
  }
}, 3000)

}
```

Comment: Is it just for demonstration reasons or do all your input fields have the same id 'h0'? If so, this could be the reason why the result is null as there is no unique field to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`closest` searches direct descendants but not siblings of the descendants e.g.

```
<div>
    <input id="#h0">
    <app-root>
        <p>
            <input id="#inputId">
        </p>
    </app-root>
</div>
```

In this HTML, calling `closest` from the `#inputId` element will only find the `div`, not the `input` because it is not a direct descendant - it is a child of `div`.

You need to modify your html so `app-root` and `#h0` are wrapped by a `div`. You can then find the closest div and select the child of that element e.g.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {

      let dummyEl = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#inputId');
      for(let i = 0; i < dummyEl.length; i++) {
        let el = dummyEl[i];

        let div = el.closest('div');
        if(div !== null) {
          console.log(div.querySelector('#h0'));
        }
      }
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Also you `id`'s must be unique so using `#h0` for each input is invalid HTML. You might be better using a class if you want to find the elements with the same "tag" e.g.

```
<input class="h0" ... >
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass data from the `AppFocusComponent`, you could use [Angular Event Emitters](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#description). The example in the documentation emits `null` in the `$event` but other data, both primitive and Objects, can be passed as well.

Here is a link to an example on [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyrtgx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**app-focus.component.ts**

First, set up an `EventEmitter` in the `AppFocusComponent`. The data can be emitted in an [Angular Lifecycle Hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). Or can be bound to a [User Input Event](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events).

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from 

'@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-focus',
  templateUrl: './app-focus.component.html'
})
export class AppFocusComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() data: any = null;
  @Output() focus = new EventEmitter();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.focus.emit(this.data);
    }, 3000)
  }

  onFocus(event: Event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.focus.emit(this.data);
  }
}
```

**app-focus.component.html**

Next, bind the `focus` event on the input to the `onFocus()` method in the component. Here, `ngModel` is used to bind the data that is emitted when the `onFocus($event)` method fires. This can either be from user input, or the data can be passed in via an `@Input()`. I wasn't sure where the data is coming from, so there a couple of approaches in the example.

```
<p>
  <input type="text" (focus)="onFocus()" [(ngModel)]="data">
</p>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  h0Value: string = '';
  h1Value: string = '';
  h2Value: string = '';
  h3Value: string = '';

  // an alternate way to set the value instead of setting it in the template
  setH1Value(event: any) {
    this.h1Value = event;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

Lastly, bind the `[value]` of the `<input>`s to their respective properties and have the `AppComponent` listen to the `(focus)` event from the `AppFocusComponent`. The data that comes from the `AppFocusComponent` can be assigned directly in the template. `(focus)="h0Value = $event"`. Or it can be wrapped in a method on the component while passing the `$event` through. `(focus)="setH1Value($event)"`. If the data is being initialized via data from an API or some other source, it can be passed in via the `@Input`. `data="h2 data"`.

The labels here are used for demonstration purposes so the data that's emitted by the `AppFocusComponent` can be viewed in the UI.

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<label>{{ h0Value }}</label>
<input type="hidden" id="h0" name="" [value]="h0Value">
<app-focus (focus)="h0Value = $event"></app-focus>

<label>{{ h1Value }}</label>
<input type="hidden" id="h1" name="" [value]="h1Value">
<app-focus (focus)="setH1Value($event)"></app-focus>

<label>{{ h2Value }}</label>
<input type="hidden" id="h2" name="" [value]="h2Value">
<app-focus data="h2 data" (focus)="h2Value = $event"></app-focus>

<label>{{ h3Value }}</label>
<input type="hidden" id="h3" name="" [value]="h3Value">
<app-focus (focus)="h3Value = $event"></app-focus>
```